# Не работает правило overflow у родителя, если у дочернего изображения свойство fixed

Tags: css

Есть следующая конструкция:

```css
.mainblock {
  display: block;
  min-height: 600px;
  width: 500px;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #0080e8;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child img {
  width: 100%;
   
  top:0px;
}

.tb {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainblock">
  <div class="tb">
    Если синоптики говорят, что завтра будет ясно, не обольщайтесь: они имеют ввиду, что сейчас им нифига неясно, а вот наступит завтра и тогда станет ясно, что за погода в этот день.
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">

      <img alt="" src="https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/001.jpg">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tb">
    Семинар "Как не стать жертвой мошенников" отменяется. Билеты возврату не подлежат.
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы изображение было зафиксировано в одном положении при прокрутке страницы, и, если ему добавить соответствующее правило `position: fixed;`, то оно выходит за пределы родительского блока - получается вот так:

```css
.mainblock {
  display: block;
  min-height: 600px;
  width: 500px;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #0080e8;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child img {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tb {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainblock">
  <div class="tb">
    Если синоптики говорят, что завтра будет ясно, не обольщайтесь: они имеют ввиду, что сейчас им нифига неясно, а вот наступит завтра и тогда станет ясно, что за погода в этот день.
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">

      <img alt="" src="https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/001.jpg">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tb">
    Семинар "Как не стать жертвой мошенников" отменяется. Билеты возврату не подлежат.
  </div>
</div>
```

Помогите разобраться почему картинка со свойством  `position: fixed;` не обрезается по границам родительского блока `.parent` у которого указано правило  `overflow: hidden;`.
Сразу оговорюсь, в моем случае использовать картинку в качестве `background` со свойством `background-attachment: fixed;` никак нельзя, изображение должно идти в теге `img`.
Если так и должно быть и это штатная ситуация, то подскажите как это можно обойти?

Comment: Что вы хотите получить? объясните подробнее.

Comment: @Duoxx Мне требуется, чтобы изображение оставалось зафиксированным при прокрутки страницы и не выходило за пределы родительского блока (в примере родитель с классом parent) т.е. все на странице скролилось, а изображение было зафиксировано в одном положении внутри родителя, к сожалению не хватает слов чтобы более доступно объяснить))

Comment: А если так то Понятно.

Comment: Могу предложить вариант с jquery

Comment: position: fixed - выпадает из потока и привязывается к указанной свойствами left, top, right и bottom точке на экране и не меняет своего положения при прокрутке веб-страницы

Comment: @Duoxx  Дело в том что, у меня эти картинки внутри родителя плавно меняются скриптом Backstretch, я уж не стал в  примере все это описывать.. Просто требуется, чтобы они были зафиксированы и обрезаны по родителю. А как вы это предлогаете сделать с помощью jquery? можно конечно попробовать, надеюсь не будет конфликтовать с Backstretch.js

Answer (score 0):

вот так???????

```css
.mainblock {
  display: block;
  min-height: 600px;
  width: 500px;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #0080e8;
    background:url(https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/001.jpg);
  background-attachment:fixed ; 
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
 
}

.child img {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tb {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainblock">
  <div class="tb">
    Если синоптики говорят, что завтра будет ясно, не обольщайтесь: они имеют ввиду, что сейчас им нифига неясно, а вот наступит завтра и тогда станет ясно, что за погода в этот день.
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">


    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tb">
    Семинар "Как не стать жертвой мошенников" отменяется. Билеты возврату не подлежат.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На выходе должно получится именно так, но как я указал в вопросе "использовать background со свойством background-attachment: fixed; никак нельзя, изображение должно идти в теге img", другими словами мне нужно такое же повторить с картинкой в теге img внутри родителя

Comment: но конечный результат должен быть точно таким, только с тегом img?

Comment: Да конечный результат должен быть таким-же как в вашем примере (без использования картинки в качестве background)

Comment: Почему Вы не можете без img? Там переменная? Если да - просто сделайте style="background-image: url(переменная)"